# Why is my CSS style not being applied correctly?

Tags: html, css

When the width> 959px I want to display is a column. 500px < width <959px, it will be 2 columns. <500px width will be a column.

**width >959px**

[image]

**500px < width <959px**

[image]

**width <500px**

[image]

```css
.img-wi{ 
        width:100%;
        display: inline-block;
        border:2px solid #13aff2;
     margin-top:10px;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width:959px) {
       .left-w{
     float:left;
     width:49%
    }
       .right-w{
     float:right;
     width:49%
    }}
.text-wi{
        border-top:2px dashed #13aff2;
        padding: 5px 0 0 20px;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width:500px) {
       .left-w{
     float:none;
     width:100%
    }
       .right-w{
     float:none;
     width:100%
    }}
```

```html
<div class="img-wi left-w">
     <img class="aligncenter" src="/new-1.png" alt="" width="288" height="64">
<div class="text-wi">
    <strong>AAAA</strong><br>
    – A<br>– B<br>– C<br>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img-wi right-w">
     <img class="aligncenter" src="/new-2.png" alt="" width="288" height="64">
<div class="text-wi"><strong>AAAA</strong><br>
    – A<br>– B<br>– C<br>
    </div></div>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: With bootstrap, this thing is very easy to do.https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp.Please refer this link

Comment: Your question is not clear, you want 1 column if the width is > 959px, 2 columns if width is between 959px and 500px, and 1 column if the width is < 500px?

Comment: I'm sorry. I corrected the question